# R Append a list wih assign

Tags: r

I want to define a list that will depend on the loop sequence and append this list with another list

```
for (i in 4:4) {
    nam <- paste0("estim",i)
    assign(nam, list(1:10))
    assign(paste0(nam,"[2]"),list(11:40))   
}


##estim4
##[[1]]
##[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

desired output

```
## estim4
## [[1]]
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

## [[2]]
##  [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
## [26] 36 37 38 39 40
```

any help please?

**update**

As mentioned by @nicola below this method is difficult to implement and granted the desired output is not exactly what I was asking for. Sorry for the imprecise question.

```
l <-  list()
for (i in 1:1) {
    l[i] <- list(list(1:10));
    l[[i]][2] <-  list(list(letters[1:4]))
}


##  l
## [[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

## [[1]][[2]]
## [[1]][[2]][[1]]
## [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Is there a simpler way to carry variable around?

Comment: What do you want exactly? I would put the results in a list, and append to that as needed. That eliminates the creation of sets of objects using `assign`.

Comment: I'd really like to know who in the hell teaches every new programmer in R to use `assign`. Don't use `assign`! Just `estim[[whatever]]<-value` works, where `whatever` is the index of the list or the name of the component.

Comment: In your desired output you don't seem to be appending anything... It looks more like splitting values 1:40 to two pots.

Comment: @nicola I didn't learn from anyone in particular :-). Your point is well taken. I proceeded this way because I have a nested list and the name of the list depend on the loop id.

Comment: The fact that you have a nested list is a further reason to not use `assign`. Just use the standard `[[` operator. It can take a variable containing the name of the element you want to modify/create.

Comment: Is this question answered then or did you update it with a new one?

Comment: Don't forget that you can also use `paste` in the assignment, like in `x[[paste0("hello", i)]] <- whatever`.  Not sure if that helps, but it's worth a note.

Comment: @nicola, what if the programmer has to assign a variable in another environment where the variable being assigned is created from a string with, say, the `glue` package in another environment?  For example:  `x<-"some_name" assign(eval("glue({x}_filename)"), 343, envir=.MyEnvironment)`?  I'm not sure if that's possible without the `assign`.  But I'd love to know if you know a way to avoid it.

Comment: @StatsStudent Not sure if I got your question correctly, but it looks to me that the standard `[[` operator is still effective: `.MyEnvironment[[glue("{x}_filename")]]<-343`.

Comment: Excellent @nicola!  I'll give this a shot.  I was trying to make use of `<-` the other day with something similar to this and could not, for the life of me figure it out so, I had to resort to `assign`.  It was killing me.  ;-)

Comment: @nicola!  And it worked.  Thanks for the great help and for improving my code.  I absolutely hated the assign call in my code. Now, thank to you, it's all gone!